# how to make line using css

Tags: html, css

I want to make a yellow line like in the image using css, but I don't have an idea how to make it, now I can only make line holes, but not vertical straight lines yet.

[image]

here is my code example

```
#holes {
  -webkit-mask: radial-gradient(circle at 120px 100%, transparent 0, transparent 62px, black 62px, black 100%);
   mask: radial-gradient(circle at 120px 100%, transparent 0, transparent 62px, black 62px, black 100%);
   background-color: #1D3962;
   background-image: radial-gradient(circle at 120px 100%, transparent 0, transparent 65px, yellow 65px, yellow 68px, transparent 68px, transparent 100%);
   width: 100%;
   height: 100vh;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: SVG or pseudo-elements + border

Answer (score 3):

I am writing one code for you that might solve your problem if you like the solution then please give it one like

You can change the value of width to make it thin or thick.

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#holes {
  -webkit-mask: radial-gradient(circle at 120px 100%, transparent 0, transparent 62px, black 62px, black 100%);
   mask: radial-gradient(circle at 120px 100%, transparent 0, transparent 62px, black 62px, black 100%);
   background-color: #1D3962;
   background-image: radial-gradient(circle at 120px 100%, transparent 0, transparent 65px, yellow 65px, yellow 68px, transparent 68px, transparent 100%);
   width: 100%;
   height: 100vh;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}

#holes::before{
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 2px;
  height: calc(100vh - 68px);
  background-color: yellow;
  margin-left: 120px;
}
```

```html
<div id="holes"></div>
```